# Как подключить QImage к проекту?

Tags: c++, qimage

#include < QImage >
Пишу так, но студия пишет что не удается найти файл

Comment: Что-то еще из Qt подключено? Я бы из vcpkg поставил.

Comment: Я вообще не шарю за QT, можете пожалуйста объяснить как все это делается?

Comment: Погуглите про vcpkg.

Comment: VC как проект сделан? из qt-проекта vс-проект делается: `qmake -t vcapp proj_name.pro`

Comment: У меня самый простой консольный проект с++

Comment: @HolyBlackCat я установил vcpkg, но по запросу QImage ничего не находит

Comment: `qt` ставьте. Еще, вам точно нужен именно `QImage`, или нужна любая библиотека для работы с картинками?

Comment: Нужна библиотека для преобразования картинки в пиксели и последующая работа с ними

Answer (score 1):

Прежде всего - у Вас вообще Qt установлен? Если нет, то действительно надо гуглить что-то вроде "как подключить qt к visual studio". Мне такой запрос выдал довольно подробные инструкции с картинками прямо на 1 странице результатов поиска. Там, правда, обычная установка через установщик Qt описывается и последующая настройка Visual Studio через окно настроек. Если Вы хотите использовать vcpkg вместо ручной установки, скорее всего придётся поменять запрос к Гуглу. Впрочем, новичкам обычно слишком много консольных команд не помогает, а мешает. Графический интерфейс обычно понятнее, если есть инструкция с картинками. Но это уже моё личное мнение. Делайте как Вам больше нравится.

Если Qt установлен, то вопрос - хоть что-то из него работает, проблема действительно только с QImage? Если только с QImage, то проблема специфическая и надо разбираться дальше.

Если же не работает ничего из Qt, то либо он установлен неправильно, либо не подключен к Студии. Убедитесь, что установлены файлы Qt, скомпилированные именно для Студии (в графическом установщике Qt можно выбрать компоненты Qt, скомпилированные разными компиляторами). Если Вы используете vcpkg, то он по идее сам выберет нужные версии. Но я с ним не работал. Делаю вывод из самого определения того, что такое менеджер пакетов.

Потом нужно указать в окне настроек Студии пути к заголовочным файлам и файлам библиотек и т.п. настройки. Это всё есть в инструкциях, которые я предлагал гуглить в начале ответа. Но это всё верно после установки вручную по старинке. Насколько это актуально после использования менеджеров пакетов, я не знаю.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, QT у меня вообще не установлен, я немного не привык просто к такой инсталяции. Буду пробовать, спасибо !